# pentaho - sharing out from one transformation to another

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have 2 files. One with stock purchase data and another with stock sales data. purchase file has stockid, count, purchaseamount. Sales data stockid, date, noofstockssold and stocksoldamount. I am able to process the purchase details and found the avg price of stocks purchased. I want to use this avg price with the stocksales data to arrive at profit/loss. I am not able to find a way to pass the avg price. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a Merge Join step to join the information of both files in one unique stream of data. It seems that the stockid would be the natural column to use to identify how to merge both files.

To use the Merge Join you previously need to sort the stream of data of both files by stockid, so previous to the Merge Join you need two Sort rows steps, one for each file.